# Formatting time for a digital clock

Tags: python, time, clock

I'm creating a function that receives the tenths of second (t) and returns a processed string (digital clock like).

Is there a better/easier/optimum way to do it?

Output format: **A:BC.D** (Minutes : Seconds . Tenths)

```py
def format(t):
    A = 0
    B = 0
    C = 0
    D = t

    if t >= 10:
        C = t // 10
        D = t % 10

        if C >= 10:
            B = C // 10
            C = C % 10

            if B >= 6:
                A = B // 6
                B = B % 6

    return str(A) + ":" + str(B) + str(C) + "." + str(D)
```

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names

Comment: Can you provide some example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those `ifs` are completely unnecessary, and a few other things can be simplified:

```py
def fmt(t):
    tenths = t % 10
    t //= 10
    sec = t % 60
    t //= 60
    min = t
    return '%d:%02d.%d' % (min, sec, tenths)

print(fmt(1234))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def format(t):
    seconds, fractions = divmod(t, 10)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return "%d:%02d.%d" % (minutes, seconds, fractions)
```

example output:

```
>>> format(10)
'0:01.0'
>>> format(100)
'0:10.0'
>>> format(1000)
'1:40.0'
```